# Installing compass succeeds, but it is not accessible

Tags: ruby, rubygems

(new to ruby here)

I am running on `CrunchBang Linux statler`.

I have uninstalled and reinstalled `compass` several times, just to make sure.

This is what I do:

```
» gem query

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

chunky_png (1.2.7)
fssm (0.2.10)
sass (3.2.5)
```

And then:

```
» sudo gem install compass
Successfully installed compass-0.12.2
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for compass-0.12.2...
Installing RDoc documentation for compass-0.12.2...
```

Let's check:

```
» gem query

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

chunky_png (1.2.7)
compass (0.12.2)
fssm (0.2.10)
sass (3.2.5)
```

And:

```
» gem which compass
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass.rb
```

But:

```
» compass
-bash: compass: command not found
```

So, what did I do wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems `gem` is broken in Ubuntu. The following is needed:

```
PATH=/var/lib/gems/1.8/bin:$PATH
```

Answer (score 6):

If you're using `rbenv`, run `$ rbenv rehash`.

Do this whenever you install a gem containing an executable (usually `.../bin/<someExecutable>`).